# JQuery Mobile - Generating a list from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

So I am working on a project, and it does involve generating a list from an XML file of ours. I have done some research on how to parse the data, and how to generate the listview.

Here is the Div which contains the ListView I am trying to access.

```
<div data-theme="c" data-role="content">
    <!--The list we shall generate-->
    <h4>Facilities</h4>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" id="facilitiesList">

    </ul>       
</div>
```

And here is the code I am using to generate the List.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#Facilities",function() {
    var xmlLoc = $.get("http://cjorchard.me.uk/ECApp/Data.xml");
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlLoc),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var output = '';
    $xml.find('item').each(function() {
        output += '<li><a href="#">' + $(this).find('Title').text() + '</a></li>'
    });
    $('#facilitiesList').html(output);
});
```

Currently, I am unsure of why it is not working. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - There are no errors being displayed either.

**EDIT 2 - I have now updated the Javascript to the following...**

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#Facilities",function() {
    var xmlLoc = $.get("http://cjorchard.me.uk/ECApp/Data.xml", function(data) {
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data),
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var output = '';
        $xml.find('item').each(function() {
            console.log($(this).find('Title').text());
            output += '<li><a href="#">' + $(this).find('Title').text() + '</a></li>'
        });
        $('#facilitiesList').html(output).listview().listview("refresh");
    });
});
```

Comment: have you put in some alert() or console.log() calls to see if output is being built as expected?  Also, final line should be $('#facilitiesList').html(output).listview("refresh");

Comment: The list isn't styled or the list isn't getting any data?

Comment: @Omar - Currently it isn't being generated.

Comment: @ezanker - I attempted updating the final line to what you stated, however received "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization". Looked into fixing that, and after doing so the list was still not generated - and with Outputting added nothing is being displayed - causing me to believe it could be the XML file. However, when looking at the XML - I see nothing wrong with the formatting.

Comment: $.get is an ajax call, so you need to process the results in the success function: $.get( "http://cjorchard.me.uk/ECApp/Data.xml", function( data ) {
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data );
  $xml = $(xmlDoc); etc...
});  api: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Also, is the xml file in your own domain, or are you making a cross domain call?

Comment: @ezanker Currently it is on my own domain, however in the future I will need to do a cross domain call which I know will cause many issues.

Comment: I've updated it using the ways you stated, @ezanker. However, I also did a check to see if it could manually input an item to the list, and it didn't work - making me believe the issue is somewhere else.<br />    var test = '<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>';           $('#facilitiesList').html(test).listview().listview("refresh");

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/h3J8j/3/ just make sure it is wrapped in a pagecreate or other jQM page event.